# Проверка пароля и подтверждение регистрации

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
def confirm_user(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    password = request.POST.get('check_pass', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(password=password)
    if user is not None:
        print("Есть совпадение")
    else:
        print("Нет совпадений")
return render(request, 'check.html')
```

Дело такое, нужно сравнить вводимый код с кодом в базе данных.

1. Метод auth.authenticate подходит для этих целей?
2. Каким образом правильнее организовать проверку? Что бы учитывать id пользователя.И менять флаг подтверждения регистрации.
   Заранее благодарен за конструктивные советы/ответы

Answer (score 3):

Метод authenticate ищет пользователя по всем бэкендам авторизации по переданным параметрам. Вообще если заглянуть в [документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users), то можно увидеть, что по умолчанию туда должен передаваться username и password (это для бэкенда ModelBackend, если вы ничего не меняли в этом плане, то ваш код не заработает).

У вас же я предполагаю, что в базе хранится некоторый email_check_code, который является, ну скажем, случайной строкой из N символов. Вы отправляете на почту пользователю некоторую ссылку, которая содержит в себе этот email_check_code, а для соответствующего пользователя записываете это значение в базу. Перешедший по этой ссылке пользователь должен увидеть сообщение, что его email подтверждён.

Из схемы выше понятно, что входными параметрами у нас являются только email_check_code (и никак не пароль). Соответственно метод authenticate нам не подходит.

Идём дальше. Реализовать это можно достаточно просто. Допустим, что вы создали некоторую related таблицу на таблицу пользователей и храните там два значения - user и email_check_code, а у пользователя пока он не подтвердит email выставляется is_active = False (ну чтоб он войти не смог). Соответственно во вьюхе нам надо проверить email_check_code, найти этого пользователя и поставить ему is_active = True. Ну и для пущего комфорта удалить инстанс этой модели с кодом (чтоб второй раз не переходил по этой же ссылке).

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import EmailCodeModel

def confirm_user(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    code_instance = EmailCodeModel.objects.filter(email_check_code=request.GET.get('email_check_code')).first()
    if code_instance:
        code_instance.user.is_active = True
        code_instance.user.save()
        code_instance.delete()
        print('Всё хорошо')
        # тут можно сделать, например, redirect на страницу успеха
return render(request, 'check.html')
```

Всё ещё не уверены? Посмотрите как это реализовано в [django-registration-redux](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/views.py#L80). А ещё лучше не утруждайте себя этим и используйте это дополнение - для простейших случаев регистрации и подтверждения email это прям то, что вам нужно (используйте backend default).

Comment: Отлично, вы прояснили мне многие вещи. Наверное я не полностью корректно задал вопрос, у меня проверка идет не по e-mail. Пользователь вводит номер телефона, генерируем код для подтверждения регистрации и высылаем пользователю, попутно записывая в бд, конечно в бд поля далеко не username & password, `password = request.POST.get('check_pass', '')` этой строкой я получаю вводимый код пользователя, мне будет проще изменить параметры authenticate, что бы получить код записанный в бд?

Comment: Проще будет напрямую искать по модели пользователя. Если надо, чтобы пользователь оставался неавторизованным пока не введёт пароль из смс, то проще хранить данные в сессии (например, придумать свою переменную _sms_user_id и ссылаться ей на настоящего пользователя)